# How to fix "unresolved external symbol _gladLoadGLLoader referenced in function _main" and "unresolved external symbol _glad_glViewport"?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glad

I keep getting the unresolved external symbol' error when building the program. However, the program compiles fine. I'm using the GLFW and GLAD libraries.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

//#undef main
int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearningOpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed To Create Window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

I keep getting the same 2 errors:

```
Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gladLoadGLLoader referenced in function _main

Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glad_glViewport
```

Comment: How are you building the program?

Comment: *LNK2019*  is a linker error, not a compile error. So the code is almost irrelevant. When you us glad then you've to compile "glad.c" and to link the resulting object file.

Comment: add glad.c in you project folder

Answer (score 50, accepted):

go to project name -> add -> existing item and then add glad.c

Comment: thanks a ton, I added the file via explorer folder and thought it'll detect lol.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually add the glad.c file that came in the 'src' directory of GLAD.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the glad/src folder via the explorer.
2. Simply drag and drop glad.c inside your Source Files of Visual Studio.

[image]